# javascript : Check if there is an array member in the entered text

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have an array of words and I want to check the entered text so that if one of the array elements is in this text, it will show me that element

and in this function I want to check it:

```
exports.words = (text)=>{
        const words = [
                'word1' , 
                'word2' , 
                'word3' , 
                'word4'
        ];
        for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            const el = words[i];
            if(el.includes(text)){
                return el;
            }else{
                return 'no words'
            }
        }
}
```

the problem is this function just return the first element (word1) And if I enter word2 or word3 in text, it returns 'no words', even though it is in the array

so how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in the *else* block inside the loop, the function is returning after executing the first iteration.

You should return `no words` from out side of the *for* loop which will guarantee the full loop execution if no match found:

```js
var words = (text)=>{
  const words = ['word1','word2','word3','word4'];
  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      const el = words[i];
      if(el.includes(text)){
          return el;
      }      
  }
  return 'no words'; //return here
}

console.log(words('word2')); //word2
console.log(words('other')); //no words
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is inside your for loop. You're returning 'no words' after only first item of an array checked, you're not even getting to second item.

```
return words.some(word => word === text) ? text : 'no words'
```

should do the job :)

Comment: The OP wants the matching array element returned, not the text, also they want an `includes()` check, not equality.

Comment: *...it will show me that element* The OP explicitly indicates that they want the element returned and their code reflects that. I stand by my downvote.